# Two fixed scrollable left sidebars

Tags: html, css

I want to create two fixed scrollable left sidebars. How can i make both of them be scrollable independent of each other?

The following code isn't working.

```css
.category {
  position: fixed;
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.sub-category {
  position: fixed;
  top: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="small-2 columns category">
  <ul>
    some list elements
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="small-2 columns sub-category">
  <ul>
    other list elements
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine, you just needed to add enough content to make the overflow active, https://jsfiddle.net/52jdmjgb/

Comment: @MattHammond, yep it should work. but it doesn't in my project. Do you know what can cause this problem?

Comment: Your code is right, unless you don't have your css linked correctly then I'm not sure what the issue could be as the code you have sent seems to be fine, if you want to upload your project to github I don't mind having a look to see if i can help :)

Comment: @MattHammond, https://github.com/yerassyl/nurate,

Comment: to save me time looking through all the files, which page you having the trouble on?

Comment: @MattHammond, app/views/layouts/left_sidebar.html.erb, and styles are in app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about ruby, so I can't help :( I really need to learn it though :)

Comment: @MattHammond, Luckily i have found the problem, i had to set bottom:0 in sub category. Thank you for trying))

Comment: hahahaahahahahahahah, I hate the little mistakes which mess it up :) no problem which I could of helped more :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/4654eaue/13/

```
<div class="small-2 columns category">
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="small-2 columns sub-category">
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
        <ul>
          some list elements          
        </ul>
</div>
```

I did nothing but add content....

Comment: hmm, it works in js fiddle, but not in my project. Guess the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few things you should note :

- `ul` needs to have a `li` tag as a containing element.
- If the two adjacent elements have fixed positioning, they would overlay, hence you need to `position` them accordingly. See the `left` propoerty I have added for a better understanding.

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.category {
    background-color: #bbb;
    position: fixed;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
.sub-category {
    background-color: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    z-index:1;
    left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="small-2 columns category">
    <ul>
        <li>some list elements</li>
        <li>some list elements</li>
        <li>some list elements</li>
        <li>some list elements</li>
        <li>some list elements</li>
        <li>some list elements</li>
        <li>some list elements</li>
        <li>some list elements</li>
        <li>some list elements</li>
        <li>some list elements</li>
        <li>some list elements</li>
        <li>some list elements</li>
        <li>some list elements</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="small-2 columns sub-category">
    <ul>
        <li>child list elements</li>
        <li>child list elements</li>
        <li>child list elements</li>
        <li>child list elements</li>
        <li>child list elements</li>
        <li>child list elements</li>
        <li>child list elements</li>
        <li>child list elements</li>
        <li>child list elements</li>
        <li>child list elements</li>
        <li>child list elements</li>
        <li>child list elements</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

display inline-block and vertical-align top

```css
body {
  height: 350px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#category {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 350px;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
#sub-category {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 350px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="category">
    <ul>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="sub-category">
    <ul>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```